# 'sub' operator not supported Dask_cudf

Tags: python, dask, rapids, cudf

I came here due a question that surged while I'm following the tutorial's methodology https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/user_guide/10min.html.

I have a dataframe imported as csv with the following structure:

```
x_tick.head()
```

- LocalTime    Ask Bid Spread
- 0    2004-10-25 00:01:01.975 86.837  86.877  0.04
- 1    2004-10-25 00:01:19.300 86.791  86.891  0.10
- 2    2004-10-25 00:01:30.759 86.812  86.842  0.03
- 3    2004-10-25 00:01:41.798 86.801  86.831  0.03
- 4    2004-10-25 00:01:42.213 86.794  86.824  0.03

`x_tick.dtypes`

- LocalTime    datetime64[ns]
- Ask                 float64
- Bid                 float64
- Spread              float64
- dtype: object

My goal would be to perform statistical tests and graph analysis, but by following the Rapids Tutorial :

```
x_tick.Spread.mean().compute()
```

> TypeError: 'sub' operator not supported between <class
> 'cudf.core.column.numerical.NumericalColumn'> and <class
> 'cudf.core.column.string.StringColumn'>

What's happening?

Thank you

Comment: There isn't enough information provided for the community to support you effectively. It's possible that one of the partitions in your `Spread` column may unexpectedly be string type, rather than float. As a starting point, you may want to try `x_tick.Spread.map_partitions(lambda x: x.dtype).compute().unique()` to investigate the dtype of every partition. [I recommend creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Another option is to enforce numeric dtype using `dd.to_numeric` (see [this blog post](https://coiled.io/blog/dask-dataframe-to-numeric-object-to-float/)). Of course, the source of the non-numeric values should be investigated for more thorough analysis.